# Compare two SDL_point?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, sdl-2

I noticed I can't directly compare two `SDL_point`s:

```
SDL_Point a = {1, 2};
SDL_Point b = {1, 2};

if (a == b) std::cout << "a = b\n"; // Doesn't compile.
if (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) // I have to do this instead.
  std::cout << "a = b\n";
```

I would like to overload the `operator==`, but since `SDL_Point` is part of **SDL**, I'm not sure how, because I may want to use the overloaded operator in many different classes of my game.

What's the normal way to do this?

Comment: Comparison operator overloads can be [free functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), not just member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have a utility or sdl_utility header that defines the operator inline:

```
inline bool operator==(SDL_Point const &a, SDL_Point const &b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}

inline bool operator!=(SDL_Point const &a, SDL_Point const &b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

You will have to include this header in any source file that wants to use the operator.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking something like that, but I wasn't sure if it's a good practice. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JoePerkins I'd say that it's fine as long as you're building a binary, and not a library. If you're making a library then you probably don't want to be throwing extra operators into your headers because then they become part of your library's interface, and if someone wants to use your library along with another library that defines its own `operator==` for `SDL_Point`, they're gonna have a bad time. You can mitigate that somewhat by keeping the operator in your library's namespace.

Comment: @JoePerkins (Unless your library's specific goal is to provide a C++ layer for SDL, that is.)

Comment: Not a library, so it should be fine. Good to know, thanks again!